# Doctrine: Use a constant in an entities assertion error message

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Is it possible to reference a class constant in an assertion's error message? Everything I tried did not work:

1. `@Assert\GreaterThan(value="foo", message="It is {User::FOO})"`
2. `@Assert\GreaterThan(value="foo", message="It is" . User::FOO)"`

Results:

1. Displays `It is {User::FOO})` literally.
2. Throws exception `[Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '.'`

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to use a constant for the message - you just cannot combine it with custom text. So the workaround is:

```
@Assert\GreaterThan(value="foo", message=User::ERROR_MESSAGE)
```

Note: `self::ERROR_MESSAGE` does not work.

Then define your two constants like this:

```
const FOO = 'foo';
const ERROR_MESSAGE = 'It is ' . self::FOO;
```